# Scrollbar does not show up in the new HandsOnTable version

Tags: jquery, handsontable

I have recently upgraded from 0.8.23 to 0.10.3 and I am facing a strange problem - the vertical scrollbar is not showing up.

I have attached 2 screenshots from the same page (one is running 0.8.23 and the other 0.10.3)

0.8.23 [image: 0.8.23]

0.10.3 [image: 0.10.3]

The code is the same.

Comment: Provide more information? Show the initialization of the table, show the html surrounding the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of that version's scrollbar working [on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VuCyT/2/).  If you post your code that will also help if you can't spot the difference.

Here is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var data = [
    ["", "Maserati", "Mazda", "Mercedes", "Mini", "Mitsubishi"],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814],
    ["2010", 5, 2905, 2867, 412, 5284],
    ["2011", 4, 2517, 4822, 552, 6127],
    ["2012", 2, 2422, 5399, 776, 4151],
    ["2009", 0, 2941, 4303, 354, 5814]
  ];

  $('#example').handsontable({
    data: data,
    minSpareRows: 1,
      scrollV: 'auto',
    colHeaders: true,
    contextMenu: true
  });


  function bindDumpButton() {
      $('body').on('click', 'button[name=dump]', function () {
        var dump = $(this).data('dump');
        var $container = $(dump);
        console.log('data of ' + dump, $container.handsontable('getData'));
      });
    }
  bindDumpButton();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just You have change in "jquery.handsontable.full.js " in this function WalkontableSettings(instance, settings) change "renderAllRows" porperty to true.